# How to safely and correctly do MPI send and receive for large number of cores

Tags: fortran, mpi

I have question with fortran and MPI, when dealing with hundreds, thousands, or tens of thousands of cores. I make my point it quick.

All the cores are doing calculation. At some point, I want rank 0 to collect the calculated the arrays from all the cores, and then rank 0 write the arrays to a file safely and correctly.

So, the task is that, I want all the cores send arrays (such as iploin, jploin, iproin, jproin, x0tot1din) to rank 0, and then rank 0 save them as iplnow, jplnow, iprnow,jprnow,x0tot1dnow, and then write them to a file.

But when dealing with like hundreds or thousands of cores, very occasionally I met some mpi_send error, or some IO error. E.g.,
forrtl: Remote I/O error.
But such error is not repeatable, like I ran the program twice, it sometimes have this error, sometimes it is just fine without any issue.

Instead of think the computing cluster may have problem, I would like to think about how to improve my code, note that x0tot1dnow can be big (like several GB), like it records the path for all the particles for all the cores in path integral. So it may take some time to write this path.

Here is an example code, I wonder could anyone give some advice how to make this send and receive and write process as robust as possible? Thank you very much indeed!

```
call barrier  ! my wrapper for mpi_barrier
if (myrank() /= 0) then
    call send(iploin,0,1) ! subroutine send is my wrapper for mpi_send, iploin is an array which the thing to be sent, 0 means send to rank 0 core, 1 means the tag)
    call send(jploin,0,2)
    call send(iproin,0,3)
    call send(jproin,0,4)
    call send(x0tot1din,0,5)           
else  ! then rank 0 begin collecting data and writing them to a file.
    open(newunit=myunit1,form='unformatted',file=trim(filename1),position='append')    
        write (myunit1) iploin
        write (myunit1) jploin
        write (myunit1) iproin
        write (myunit1) jproin
        write (myunit1) x0tot1din
        
        do i=1,nproc()-1  ! nproc() give the total number of core involved. 
            call recv(iplnow,i,1) ! recv is my wrapper for mpi_receive, iplnow is new name for the received iploin, i means the receive from the ith rank, 1 means the tag. 
            call recv(jplnow,i,2)
            call recv(iprnow,i,3)
            call recv(jprnow,i,4)
            call recv(x0tot1dnow,i,5)    
            
            write (myunit1) i
            write (myunit1) iplnow
            write (myunit1) jplnow
            write (myunit1) iprnow
            write (myunit1) jprnow
            write (myunit1) x0tot1dnow  
            
        enddo      
   
    close(myunit1) 
endif
```

Comment: What are the errors that you see?

Comment: @francescalus  for example,    forrtl: Remote I/O error.  But I am not sure if it is the cluster's problem or really my code's bug. So I wish to see if someone could give perhaps some suggestions as to how to do receive/send safely and correctly.

Comment: MPI implementations do have limits, and often don't handle things gracefully when they are met, so it could be a "cluster" problem in that sense. If you can say which MPI you are using, closer estimates of array sizes, whether you have any backtraces on error, and see problems with the MPI calls directly, then that's all potentially useful information.

Comment: Gathering data on one rank so it can be written by that rank is a wrong pattern, especially at scale. Instead, use MPI-IO collectives and have each rank writes it’s own data.

Comment: MPI-IO, or, alternatively, libraries like NetCDF or HDF5 that save in parallel to a structured data format.

Comment: Right, adding ADIOS to the list.